# Cheerio find method not able to find when scraping

Tags: jquery, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I am using the following code

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var url = "http://www.mbl.is/feeds/fp/";
request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    $ = cheerio.load(body,{xmlMode : true});
    $('item').each(function(item, xmlItem){
        console.log($(xmlItem).find('title').text());
        console.log($(xmlItem).find('link').text());
        console.log($(xmlItem).children()[3]['children'][0]['data']);
    });
});
```

And my problem is, why can't the third line in the .each loop be

```
console.log($(xmlItem).find('pubDate').text());
```

If I use that line the output is empty but the structure of the downloaded xml file tells me that should not be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-configure the cheerio object adding `lowerCaseTags` flag;

```
$ = cheerio.load(body, {
  xmlMode: true,
  lowerCaseTags: true
});
```

Now `console.log($(xmlItem).find('pubDate').text());` should work fine.